# Evidences supporting that coronavirus (SARS-CoV-2) came from bats

Tags: bioinformatics, virology, coronavirus

I was trying to find evidence that the coronavirus (SARS-CoV-2) came from bats. So far I know that coronavirus shared 96.2% overall genome sequence identity with a bat coronavirus RaTG13 from horseshoe bats who identified as natural hosts for SARS-related coronaviruses which were the direct progenitors for the origin of SARS-CoV and also comparing the receptor-binding domain (RBD) of 2019-nCoV to SARS-CoV, the structure of the RBD allowed for the use of ACE2 (angiotensin-converting enzyme 2) as an entry receptor. I wanted to know that apart from these two pieces of evidence are there any major evidence that also suggests that indeed SARS-CoV-2 came from bats.

Comment: I think the current consensus is that SARS-CoV-2 didn't *originate* in bats, but rather passed through them from another species before jumping to humans. I don't believe that other species has been identified yet, but I may be wrong - this is from news reports.

Comment: @MattDMo Isn't the hypothesis the reverse? I mean the virus existed in bats, then was passed to another species, then to humans?